# How to use a function called "val()" in Kotlin? / extend external JS classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I encountered a problem while trying to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) with **Kotlin**.

When accessing data from a *database trigger* you use the `snapshot.val();` function in *Javascript*. In *Kotlin* this is **not** possible because `val` is a keyword in *Kotlin*. I managed a way to go around this by using

```
snapshot.`val()`
```

This way I can call functions with any name in *Kotlin*. Now I think that it is really annoying to type this "grave accent" (`) thingy every time, so I tried to create an extension function.

My problem with that is that I do not know how to reference the type. In *Javascript* it is [`DeltaSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#val) or [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) when accessing the database.

How do I extend external classes or how can I call it by a different name?
Typealiases won't work because they are limited to classes / instead of supporting functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try following?

```
external class MyClass {
    @JsName("val")
    fun foo()
}
```

Comment: How do we use this My class as Snapshot's replacement? Where to put this class?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a class is an object aswell

```
snapshot['val']();
```

---

**More generic**

```
object[functionName]();

object[functionName].call(object, ...args);

object[functionName].apply(object, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
js("snapshot.val()").yourKotlinCode
```

it works for me

Comment: Can you create an extension function this way? Otherwise this is even more complicated than the *grave accent*.

Comment: try this:

`fun Any.jsVal() = asDynamic()?.\`val()\``

and then in your code:

`snapshot.jsVal().yourCode`

Comment: upd: sorry, my previous comment is wrong. It seems to be impossible